# Chrome for IOS CORS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm experiencing an odd issue. I have a well (as I thought) setup CORS on my server, but it works just once after page refresh. All other requests become skipped or dropped. The XHR has status **0** and there's no response text (i know it's silly to expect any text for HTTP 204) or statusText, but readyState is **4**.

Request OPTIONS headers:

```
OPTIONS http://domain2.xx HTTP/1.1
Host: domain2.xx
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://domain1.xx
Accept: */*,image/webp
Referer: http://domain1.xx/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/47.0.2526.107 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1.46
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4</i>
```

Response OPTIONS headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 19 Dec 2015 14:56:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Cookie,X-Requested-With,Accept,Authorization,Accept-Language,Content-Language,Last-Event-ID,X-HTTP-Method-Override
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.xx
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Max-Age: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Set-Cookie: ******; Expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT; Max-Age=315576000; Path=/; HttpOnly
Connection: keep-alive
```

This happens only in Chrome on iOs. All other browsers behave good. (Under all I mean IE8+, Chrome(Win7+,MacOs,Linux,Android), FF(Win7+,MacOsX,Linux,Android), Safari (MacOsX, iOs), Opera (Win7+,Linux,Android,iOs), Coast iOs, UC Browser ( android, iOs ) and may be I could forget some where this works ok).

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? i am facing a similar issue.